# Delete sesion key in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Im trying to execur some javascript code if a session variable is set

```
@if(Session::get('refactor') == true)
<script>
    //some javascript code
</script>
{{ Session::forget('refactor') }}
@endif
```

But `{{ Session::forget('refactor') }}` its not working

Comment: you don't need to write `== true`  bcz if statement will also execute if it has refactor key...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @php tag for this:

```
@if(session('refactor'))
    <script>
        //some javascript code
    </script>
    @php
        request()->session()->forget('refactor');
    @endphp
@endif
```

I would recommend doing the logic in the Controller though: pass a variable that contains your script or empty depending on the session content.

You can learn more in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session